# How to insert HTML and CSS into a web page from a HTML template file using JavaScript? - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension and attempting to insert a large amount of HTML and CSS into a webpage when the browser action button is clicked.

So far I have a working test version but it is a mess and I want to clean it up.

Currently, the background.js file is calling the content.js file to run by passing a message to it when the browser action is clicked. The content.js file contains a function which is then called. This then generates the HTML and CSS via commands such as:

```
function buildExtensionUI() {
    var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
    myDiv.id = "myDiv";
    myDiv.style.position = "fixed";
}
```

This div also has other divs, text, buttons, etc inside it. The function currently has close to 100 lines of javascript code, similar to as seen above to generate the HTML, give them all ids, and style the CSS, and I have much more I want to add. I have tested the code I have and it is doing what I want it to for now.

However, I want to extract the code into HTML and CSS "template files" so that I can work with them and edit them properly. This will eventually be a very large application so I want to do this now before I progress any further.

I have Googled extensively and have not yet found a working solution. I have created an HTML template file - e.g:

```
<template>
    <div id="myDiv">
        <div id="closeButton">
            &times;
        </div>

        <div id="centerDiv">
            <h1 id="title">
                My Title
            </h1>

            <h2 id="subTitle">

            </h2>

            <textarea name="textBox" id="textBox" cols="50" rows="4"></textarea>

            <button type="submit" id="button">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

and a style.css file which references the id of the HTML file. The HTML will have to be dynamically updated with Javascript eventually also.

Is it possible to create a Javascript variable or object which loads the HTML template file which can then be injected in the webpage when the user activates the browser action? Can it be done is background.js and then sent as an object/variable to content.js?

What other possible solutions are there?

Any questions please ask and I can clarify.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use `ajax` call to get html, then pass it in variable and use whenever you need to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background script can only send simple JSON-compatible data in messages so it can't send a DOM element such as `template`. It can read files from the extension directory into a string via `fetch('/file.html')`, then send it to the content script, which will either assign it to `innerHTML` of an element or use `DOMParser` API. But HTML parsing of such a big string would be slow. You would also have to use ShadowDOM to isolate CSS.

There's a simpler and faster solution: create an iframe element in the content script that points to a html file in your extension that's exposed via [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) in manifest.json. Inside that HTML file you can do anything you want, load any scripts you need. The next step would be to use a library like React or Vue or Svelte inside that file that compiles your HTML into virtual DOM. Look for tutorials on that by googling "web_accessible_resources iframe content script".

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I am attempting the iframe solution however the iframe that's created in the content script is not seeing the HTML file in the extension folder. It is instead attempting to find it in WEBSITE.com/iframe.html. It seems as if I will have to load the iframe in the background script and somehow send it over to the content script. Is this possible?

Comment: It is now seeing the iframe after using chrome.extension.getURL() but now it's giving an error of "Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at buildiFrame"

Comment: I can't help without seeing [MCVE](/help/mcve). Sounds like you're trying to combine the two approaches which is not what I suggested.

Comment: Fixed it. Thank you.